# Dymola flag equidistant time grid and store variables at events

Tags: modelica, dymola

Is there a flag/scripting way of specifying for a simulation :

- Store variable at events, same as Simulation Setup\Output\Store variables at events
- Equidistant time grid, same as Simulation Setup\Output\Equidistant time grid

I know it can be added as an annotation in model :

`annotation experiment(__Dymola_NumberOfIntervals=501), __Dymola_experimentSetupOutput(equdistant=true, events=true));`

Regards,
Gilles

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "flag/scripting"? You can set the simulation grid via the Dymola GUI, via Dymola scripting commands or via model annotations (as you've shown). What are you looking for?

Comment: Hi, I actually I don't want to set the simulation setup via the Dymola GUI nor model annotations. I want to set it via a script and execute the script in a .bat file.

Comment: https://www.claytex.com/tech-blog/simulation-settings-class-annotation/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in from the Dymola support. See the Dymola user manual V1 p 501 on the simulator API :

```
experimentSetupOutput(...)
  input Boolean textual := false "Textual storage";
  input Boolean doublePrecision := false "Double precision";
  input Boolean states := true "Store state variables";
  input Boolean derivatives := true "Store derivative variables";
  input Boolean inputs := true "Store input variables";
  input Boolean outputs := true "Store outputs variables";
  input Boolean auxiliaries := true "Store auxiliary variables";
  input Boolean equdistant := true "Store equidistantly";
  input Boolean events := true "Store variables at events";
  input Boolean debug := false "Write log messages";
  output Boolean ok;
```

Therefore the flags to set before the simulateModel command were :

```
experimentSetupOutput(events=false,equdistant=true);
```